# XCode 8.2.1 UIView Has no member 'load request'

Tags: uiview

I am running the following code and receiving the following error. I have searched but cannot see the precise answer. Really appreciate all assistance. 
New to IOS Development so still working through 
Thanks

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var WebView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL:NSURL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.mainbundle().pathForResource("mashupcode",ofType:"html")!)!))
        // This is the web mashup
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    }
```

ERROR

> Valueoftype 'UIView' has no member 'loadRequest

Answer (score 0):

Look:

```
@IBOutlet var WebView: **UIView**!
```

Your webView variable is actually a UIView object. You need an actual UIWebView here instead of UIView. Probably check your storyboard and make sure you have connected the proper iboutlet.